# How to embed Python script into C++?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, embed

I am embedding a python web-crawler script into C++. C++ will be used for input of website urls and fields, I may change the output method to be controlled using C++. I am stuck at building the C++ portion of it.

How do i implement this with my web scraping script?

`   static int numargs=0;

```
/* Return the number of arguments of the application command line */
static PyObject*
emb_numargs(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, ":numargs"))
    return NULL;
    return PyLong_FromLong(numargs);
 }

 static PyMethodDef EmbMethods[] = {
     {"numargs", emb_numargs, METH_VARARGS,
      "Return the number of arguments received by the process."},
     {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
  };

  static PyModuleDef EmbModule = {
         PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, "emb", NULL, -1, EmbMethods,
         NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    }

 static PyObject*
 PyInit_emb(void)
 {
    return PyModule_Create(&EmbModule);
}
```

`

Comment: Where exactly do you have trouble? What is your question? How can we help you? Have you read https://docs.python.org/3.8/extending/embedding.html?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do I/O with C++ and the computation work with Python. Usually you would do it the other way round